# Calculated column formula for not equal

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column-formula

Hi can I use the `<>` operator in a SharePoint Calculated column?  The following formula is accepted but I'm not sure it is supported.  My requirement is:

> If any values equal High AND are not equal to Low then C, else B

```
=IF(OR([field1]="High",[field2]="High",[field3]="High",[field4]="High",[field5]="High",[field6]="High"),"High",IF(OR([field1]<>"Low",[field2]<>"Low",[field3]<>"Low",[field4]<>"Low",[field5]<>"Low",[field6]<>"Low"),"C","B"))
```

If the statement is not supported, how can I write a `<>` statement?

Comment: The normal way would be to finagle **=NOT([Column1]+[Column2]=24)** type statement into it, but I'm not sure ... I have no way to test this at home.

Comment: The formula is standard Excel formula I think, so I think it should work with <>. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx